# Getting 404 on images in public folder using a custom function in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to use a simple function to auto-populate the images in a gallery page, but getting 404's on the images. Everything else is working as intended.

I'm using material css and all of that fluff is working correctly. I'm getting the correct number of image cards.

The path echoed out correctly, and within the function the name of the images is being generated with no issues. I'm using the {{asset}} function of Laravel and my images are in the public folder, so access shouldn't (?) be an issue.

```php
public static function addImg($dirname){
$images = scandir($dirname);
$ignore = Array(".", "..");
foreach($images as $curimg){
    if(!in_array($curimg, $ignore)) {
        echo "<div class='col s12 m6 l4'>
        <img src='{{asset({$dirname}{$curimg})}}' class='materialbox responsive-img card'>$curimg
    </div>";
    }
}       
}
```

and the call is

```php
{{$gallery::addImg('/css/img/')}}
```

Console shows `"GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/%7B%7Basset(~snip for privacy~/public/css/img/hero%20(2).jpg)%7D%7D 404 (Not Found)"`

Comment: Looks like an absolute path is used in the url, which is probably not working. You'll have to remove the part before `/css/img/...`

Comment: @Rolf Great catch! Unfortunately it did not correct the issue, now I'm getting `GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/%7B%7Basset(hero%20(2).jpg)%7D%7D 404 (Not Found)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Blade syntax in a regular string. It isn't going to be parsed. You have to return the string how you actually need it to be.

Any interpolation you need has to be done while defining the string like any other regular string in PHP.

```
$location = asset($dirname . $curimage);

echo "<img src='{$location}' ...>{$curimage}";
```

Also you are calling `{{ $gallery::addImg(...) }}` which doesn't return anything that could be echoed by Blade. `{{ }}` is for echoing in Blade, it is not for just executing PHP statements.

This sounds like something you could make into a custom Blade directive though.

Comment: I was using it after injecting the function from a controller. `@inject('gallery', 'App\Http\Controllers\gallery')` is that not accepted practice?  Sorry for the newbie question, trying to wrap my head around the nuances of blade and Laravel.

Comment: if you would like, but that isn't the issue ... you have to build the string with normal PHP interpolation, if you put `{{ }}` in your string that is literally `{{ }}`, a string isn't Blade

Comment: Yup, I was just clarifying that bit while i implemented your fix, which was 100% what I was missing, thanks! For further reference in case anyone is reading this answer in the future, I also needed to add public_path to my images variable (a bug that popped up after the other was resolved)

Comment: no problem ... you needed `public_path` for your `scandir` call?

Comment: I did, since I'm only passing through the "/css/img/" bit to the function through `$dirname`. Was getting a "file not found" error.

Comment: just making sure it is clear to anyone else who comes through in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use blade syntax inside a string because blade will parse only the `.blade.php` file.

But you can just use simple php concatenation:

```
public static function addImg($dirname){
    $images = scandir($dirname);
    $ignore = Array(".", "..");
    foreach($images as $curimg){
        if (!in_array($curimg, $ignore)) {
            echo "<div class='col s12 m6 l4'>
            <img src='" . asset($dirname . $curimg) . "' class='materialbox responsive-img card'>$curimg
        </div>";
        }
    }       
}
```